# How can I refresh single cells in a report of cube formula?

Tags: excel, cube, olap-cube

I have a report built with Cube Formula which is refreshed and issued daily and the source data cube is refreshed mid-morning each day.

I would like to refresh the latest row of cells (yesterday's data) without refreshing the whole report.

Does anyone know how to refresh singular or grouped cells?

Comment: Try looking here for more details about refreshing only selected cells. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_windows8/how-do-i-refresh-a-formula-on-selected-number-of/c416df88-6096-4b7f-9e0f-61e712c1dccd

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seem to relate to cube formula